# JSF 2.2 @ViewScoped binding bug?

Tags: jsf, binding, view-scope, jsf-2.2

I've read about the binding bug with @ViewScoped ([BUG REPORT](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492)) and that it was fixed in one of the latest versions of JSF, so I tested this with the 3 latest versions of JSF and tried using the

```
  <context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
```

fix to solve it, but no luck.

I have a primefaces datatable where I have filters in each column header.

```
        <p:column id="cpfHeader" sortBy="#{cliente.nrCpf}"
        filterMatchMode="contains">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <h:outputText value="CPF" />
                <p:inputText value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.nrCpf}">

                </p:inputText>
                <p:commandButton
                    actionListener="#{cadastroClienteBean.getClientesBusca}"
                    update="#{form}:tabelaCliente:tblCliente" value="Filtrar"></p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </f:facet>
                #{cliente.nrCpf}                
            </p:column>
```

Before I changed the JSF version, everytime I'd click on the "Filtrar" button, a new instance of my cadastroClienteBean would be created. Now that I've changed it, it seems that the ManagedBean is not being instantiated everytime, but the cliente variable is becoming null, eventhough I instantiate it on the constructor.

```
    public CadastroClienteBean(){
    cliente = new Cliente();
    init();
}
```

EDIT: After debugging a bit I found out that the value of the filter is being set on the variable and right after that the setCliente() is being called and setting it to null, but I don't know why.

Comment: Did you mark the `client` property `transient`? You shouldn't.

Comment: No, I didn't `@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroClienteBean implements  Serializable {
 
 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private List<Cliente> clientes;
 private Cliente cliente; 
 private String valor;`

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what was happening the `selection="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente}"` attribute on the dataTable was setting the client to null since there was no line selected.

Comment: Okay, that's thus just a bug in your own code / testing methodology ;) By the way, with JSF 2.2 you should not have the need to disable partial state saving to fix the bug of view scoped bean being reconstructed everytime. This setting is only intented as "temporary workaround" when you're still on JSF 2.0/2.1.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it by using another Cliente attribute "selectedCliente". And removed the partial state saving fix. Thanks.